# Disable Ligatures in WeasyPrint

Tags: css, weasyprint

I'm generating a PDF report with WeasyPrint using a font (Lato) that has ligatures for some combinations of letters. Notably, it will ligature together "ti" into a single character, which then proceeds to display incorrectly (it isn't in line with the other text). Which CSS rules can be used to prevent these ligatures from displaying?

Choosing a font without said ligatures can't be done, as I'm trying to make a printed generated report adhere to a similar style as the web application that generates it.

Comment: it might be that your particular font has ligature defect.

weasyprint uses cairo/pango to render fonts, and pango had been without ligatures, until they made it as feature. after patch has been introduced, complains started to land, and it looked like fonts had ligatures introduced at guess - read [this snippet](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-i18n-list/2006-January/msg00044.html) from Gnome mailing list back in 2006